# What rules apply when Saving Throw proficiencies overlap?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, racial-traits, proficiency, mtg-plane-shift

I'm a playing in a custom setting. The DM says all races are allowed, including the [Human (Keldon) variant](https://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/magic/Plane_Shift_Dominaria.pdf#page=19), from the [*Plane Shift: Dominaria*](https://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/magic/Plane_Shift_Dominaria.pdf) handbook. One of the traits of the race is this:

> ***Keldon Resilience.*** You have proficiency in Strength saving throws.

If the character class (such as Barbarian or Fighter) already has proficiency in Strength saving throws, is this trait just redundant? If not, what rules apply?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Multiple of the same proficiency does nothing

Having two features which tell you that you have proficiency in a given saving throw (or any other roll), you still only have proficiency in the roll and add it once. That Keldon trait thus does nothing if your class already has proficiency in the saving throw (you can ask your DM about replacing the saving throw proficiency with another saving throw, their call. They may want to limit you to gaining proficiency in Intelligence or Charisma instead, as those are generally considered similar to Strength in their usefulness. Dexterity, Wisdom or Constitution saves come up more frequently and are thus generally better).

The relevant rule preventing proficiency duplication from doing anything is found both in chapter 1 (Proficiency bonus section of step 2) and 7 (under Proficiency bonus), beyond proficiency being defined as a boolean (so you can only be or not be proficient) reads:

> Your proficiency bonus can’t be added to a single die roll or other number more than once. For example, if two different rules say you can add your proficiency bonus to a Wisdom saving throw, you nevertheless add the bonus only once when you make the save.

It may be worth noting that saving throws are not included in the optional rule for changing the proficiencies granted by your race in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (See Customizing your Origin > Proficiencies). This is presumably due to none of the official race options granting saving throw proficiencies.

Comment: Agreed, if a proficiency swap is allowed, it should be limited to one of the other two "secondary" proficiencies, and not the classic Ref/Fort/Will (Dex/Con/Wis).  Most things are balanced around the idea that the classic trio still do the heavy lifting, and the other three are more for fleshing out unusual abilities/spells/etc., so it would be best to not turn a secondary into a primary.

Answer (score 6):

#### No official races give saving throw proficiencies.

There are no rules for this type of interaction because there is no officially published way for a race and a class to have a saving throw proficiency overlap.

Just ask your DM to sub for a different saving throw proficiency if your choice of class results in an overlap there is an overlap. Otherwise having two instances of one saving throw proficiency is no different than having one.